# Analysing a site (UX - language)

Tags: ux-field, selling-ux, component

[image: case in point]

A bit of a strange question. I'm looking at a website to try and work out the thinking behind the components, positioning and or funnels but am finding it hard to find the right language. For example looking at the hero I can say that this is usually where the "value proposition" is situated - the example attached has a "social endorsement" of some sort but apart from that I'm unable to articulate this page - does this make sense, can anyone help?

what makes this homepage effective?

Answer (score 1):

You won't know that the homepage is effective until you ask your audience.

Plan some A/B testing and let the results decide.

Comment: I completely understand, and that is the usual approach. I'm thinking more academic. For instance, every site uses a hero, it's the value proposition and in this case, is using social endorsement. There has to be some thought before A/B testing; that's the part I'm looking for.